# Python Pandas How to read json without sorting by the index?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

If i have a json file like this, and import it to dataframe, the column order is always sort -0.8, -0.9. i want the order maintain as it is defined in the json which is -0.9, -0.8

```html
{
    "-0.90": {
        "A": 1.0,
        "B": 0.4935585804
    },
    "-0.80": {
        "A": 1.0,
        "B": 0.4935585804
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can load load your json data as an OrderedDict to preserve the order of the keys, and then use the `DataFrame.from_dict` constructor:

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

s = """{
    "-0.90": {
        "A": 1.0,
        "B": 0.4935585804
    },
    "-0.80": {
        "A": 1.0,
        "B": 0.4935585804
    }
}"""

data = json.loads(s, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

      -0.90     -0.80
A  1.000000  1.000000
B  0.493559  0.493559
```